# Delete the data from database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am new in iPhone programming and I dont know much about database. I am making an iphone application in which I have used database for storing the contacts, whenever I add new contact It get add to the table view where others contacts are displaying. But I want that If I dont need any contact then by clicking on the row of the table view it must delete from tableview as well as from database. How Can I do it. Please help me.

Thanks alot.

Comment: You need to provide some details to which database you are using and how, e.g. sqlite, CoreData, plist, etc...

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        ;

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }   

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tutorial of sqlite: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

you'll use `sqlite3_prepare_v2` but I know there are some helper frameworks out there that people will recommend (I haven't used them so can't comment)